# Como retornar uma coluna de uma query dentro de classe

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos, funções, pdo, classes

Estou atualizando meu projeto todo para PDO orientado a objeto, porém estou tendo algumas dificuldades pra retornar uma coluna de um fetch na query da classe `User`. Depois de várias tentativas, assim ficou meu código:

**user.php**

```
Class User {

    public $usr_idLogged = 1;

    public function selectUser() {

        try {

            $classConnection = new Connection();
            $openConn = $classConnection->openConn();

            $stmt = $openConn->prepare('SELECT * FROM tbl_users a JOIN tbl_users_picture b ON a.usr_id = b.usrPic_idUser WHERE usr_id = :usr_id;');
            $stmt->bindParam(':usr_id', $usr_idLogged);
            $stmt->execute();
            $usr_idLogged_f = $stmt->fetch();
        }
        catch (PDOException $e) {
            echo "There is some problem in connection: " . $e->getMessage();
        }
    }   
}
```

E aqui está a página onde quero exibir um resultado por vez.

**panel.php**

```
              $classUser = new User();
              $classUser->selectUser();


              if ((!empty($classUser->usr_idLogged_f['usrPic_path'])) && (file_exists($classUser->usr_idLogged_f['usrPic_path']))) {
                  echo '<img class="image--profile" src="'.$classUser->usr_idLogged_f['usrPic_path'].'" title="Open your profile">';
              }
              else {
                echo '<img class="image--profile" src="images/user_m.png">';
              }
```

No caso eu quero exibir a coluna do `fetch` que dei, mas eu sempre acabo em um erro diferente relacionado à variavel, no caso `usr_idLogged_f['usrPic_path'])`.

Answer (score 1):

Existem algumas formas de você resolver esse problema.
Você pode declarar o seu método como estático e assim instanciar o obejto direto.
(Não rodei seu código, por isso minha dica vai no escuro)

Segue abaixo o mencionado:

```
<?php
class User {

    public $usr_idLogged = 1;

    public static function selectUser() {

        try {
            $classConnection = new Connection();
            $openConn = $classConnection->openConn();

            $stmt = $openConn->prepare('SELECT * FROM tbl_users a JOIN tbl_users_picture b ON a.usr_id = b.usrPic_idUser WHERE usr_id = :usr_id;');
            $stmt->bindParam(':usr_id', $usr_idLogged);
            $stmt->execute();
            $usr_idLogged_f = $stmt->fetch();
        }
        catch (PDOException $e) {
            echo "There is some problem in connection: " . $e->getMessage();
        }
      }
     }
    ?>
```

Porém, como você está fazendo em PDO, é ideal que você faça os Getters e Setteres, para depois criar os métodos e criaria uma class de conexão. Como eu não sei como a sua conexão está sendo feita, eu mandarei um exemplo e como ficariam os dois arquivos.

**Class Conexão**

```
<?php
class Connection extends PDO{
    private $conn;
    //Conexão automática ao banco de dados
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->conn = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=dbphp7", "root","");//Pode ser passado por paramêtros com bindParam caso exista mais de um servidor
    }
    //Associação de parâmetros passados
    private function setParams($statment, $parameters = array()){
        //Com este foreach, é possível passar quantos parâmetros necessários
        foreach ($parameters as $key => $value) {
            //O $this->setParam está chamando o método abaixo, no qual executa o bind de apenas um parâmetro, porém, devido ao foreach, este bind será executado quantas vezes for necessário
            $this->setParam($statment, $key, $value);
        }
    }
    //Ao contrário do método setParams, este executa o bind de apenas um parâmetros, por isso o nome Param, pois é apenas um
    private function setParam($statment, $key, $value){
        $statment->bindParam($key, $value);
    }
    //Execução de um comando ao banco
    public function query($rawQuery/*Query bruta que será tratada depois*/, $param = array())
    {
        //Comando de execução no banco
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($rawQuery);
        //Chamando o métododo setParams e associando os parâmetros statement = $stmt e parameter = $param.
        //A variável $stmt está chamando o comando de execução no banco.
        //A variável $param está recebendo o array
        //Cada variável passada refere-se a exigência do método setParams
        $this->setParams($stmt, $param);
        //Executando
        $stmt->execute();
        //Retornando a execução
        return $stmt;
    }
    //Método para o select
    public function select($rawQuery, $params = array()):array{
        //O $stmt é o que o método quey retorna
        $stmt = $this->query($rawQuery, $params);
        //Retorna o fetchAll com os dados associativos
        return $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    }
}
?>
```

**Class de métodos**

```
<?php
class User {

    public $usrPic_path;

    public function setUsrPic_path($usrPic_path){
        $this->usrPic_path = $usrPic_path;
    }
    public function getUsrPic_path($usrPic_path){
        return $this->usrPic_path;
    }

    public function setData($data){
        //Envia os dados, por vetor e row, para os métodos setters
        $this->UsrPic_path($data["usrPic_path"]);
    }

    public function selectUser() {
        $openConn = new Connection();
        $resultado = $openConn->prepare('SELECT * FROM tbl_users a JOIN tbl_users_picture b ON a.usr_id = b.usrPic_idUser WHERE usr_id = :usr_id;', array(
            ':usr_id'=>$usrPic_path
        ));
        if(count($resultado)>0){
            $this->setData($resultado[0]);
        }
    }   
}
?>
```

**AutoLoad da conexão nas classes**

```
<?php
//Auto load das classes
spl_autoload_register(function($class_name){
    //Passa o nome do arquivo
    $filename = "class". DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR .$class_name.".php";
    //Se este arquivo existir, ele é invocado
    if (file_exists(($filename))){
        require_once($filename);
    }
});
?>
```

**Index**

```
<?php
    include('user.php');

    $classUser = new User();
    $classUser_select = $classUser->usr_idLogged;

    if ((!empty($classUser_select)) && (file_exists($classUser_select))) {
        echo '<img class="image--profile" src="'.$classUser_select.'" title="Open your profile">';
    }
    else {
    echo '<img class="image--profile" src="images/user_m.png">';
    }
?>
```

Espero ter ajudado.